# Vagrant up throws parse error

Tags: vagrant, yaml, hyper-v, vagrantfile

I'm trying to run vagrant using hyper as provider, following this [guide](https://code.johnpbloch.com/2015/07/laravel-homestead-on-hyperv/).
But when I run 'vagrant up' I get the following error:

```
    $ vagrant up
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse': (<unknown>): found a tab character that violate intendation while scanning a plain scalar at line 21 column 7 (Psych::SyntaxError)
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse_stream'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:318:in `parse'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:245:in `load'
        from E:/www/Homestead/Vagrantfile:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.3/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.3/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.3/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:113:in `block (2 levels) in load'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.3/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.3/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `block in load'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.3/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.3/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `load'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.3/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:28:in `initialize'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:740:in `new'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:740:in `vagrantfile'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:486:in `host'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:208:in `block in action_runner'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:473:in `hook'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:722:in `unload'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.3/bin/vagrant:177:in `ensure in <main>'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.3/bin/vagrant:177:in `<main>'
```

E:/www/Homestead/Vagrantfile:20:in `block in ' gives me reason to believe that this is where there the parse error occurs.

Line 20 from vagrantfile loads homestead.yaml:

```
        Homestead.configure(config, YAML::load(File.read(homesteadYamlPath)))
```

And this is my homestead.yaml.
I've check its validity with http://www.yamllint.com/ , which says it is valid.

```
    --- 
authorize: C:\Users\xxx\.sshid_rsa.pub
box: johnpbloch/homestead
cpus: 1
databases: 
  - homestead
folders: 
  - 
    map: ~/Code
    to: /home/vagrant/Code
ip: "192.168.10.10"
keys: 
  - ~/.ssh/id_rsa
memory: 2048
provider: virtualbox
sites: 
  - 
    map: homestead.app
    to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
```

Why am I getting this error, and how do I fix this error?

Comment: Actual error message is: `found a tab character that violate intendation while scanning a plain scalar at line 21 column 7`. But the yaml file you show contains only 19 lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when you see this error, you should look the homestead.yaml file. there is space or enter extra.

```
 - 
    map: ~/Code
```

should be :

```
- map: ~/Code
```

and

```
- 
    map: homestead.app
```

should be :

```
 - map: homestead.app
```